# Detecting what type of block is broken - spigotMC

Tags: events, minecraft, bukkit

So... I'm trying to make a plugin that when a stone block/cobblestone block is broken, it has a 99% chance for a silverfish to spawn. I know how to do the randomness part, but I can't seem to make the code that checks if the block broken is a stone block. Can someone help me? Make sure to test before you upload (because in my previous question I had 1 person who didn't test)

Here is what I tested:

```
Block block = (Block) e.getBlock();
if (block == Material.STONE){
    block.getWorld().spawnEntity(block.getLocation, EntityType.SILVERFISH); 
    // I do know that blocks can't have an equality to a material, but I already tried as much as I could
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempt. Even if you have no idea how to check, at least post the code that does it to all blocks without checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Instead of `block == Material.STONE`, do `block.getType() == Material.STONE`.

Comment: Looks reasonable to me, I'll try this when I get home (I'm in school right now)